# MySQL syntax error when I try to execute an SQL query via JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I’m building a Java microservice that uses [AWS Aurora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Aurora) MySQL for some operations. The code connects to the database fine and the first three queries I had were throwing a similar error till I realized I was missing semicolons.

The final query (the update statement), however, is still giving me the same syntax error even with the semicolon and I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is the code below:

```
try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);

            setupStatement = conn.createStatement();
            idInsertStatement = conn.createStatement();
            secretNumberUpdateStatement = conn.createStatement();

            String createTableIfNotExists = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS secret_number_generator(id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, secret_number VARCHAR(20);";

            String generateSecretId = "INSERT INTO secret_number_generator VALUES(null,null);";

            String getLastRecordId = "SELECT id FROM secret_number_generator ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";

            setupStatement.addBatch(createTableIfNotExists);
            idInsertStatement.addBatch(generateSecretId);
            setupStatement.executeBatch();
            idInsertStatement.executeBatch();
            readStatement = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            resultSet = readStatement.executeQuery(getLastRecordId);

            while(resultSet.next()){
                id = String.valueOf(resultSet.getLong("id"));
            }

            /*
              Logic for setting up secretNumber
            */

            }
            secretNumber = "R" + env + id + randomDigit;

            String updateSecretNumber = "UPDATE secret_number_generator SET secret_number = " + secretNumber + " WHERE id = " + id + ";";

            secretNumberUpdateStatement.addBatch(updateSecretNumber);
            secretNumberUpdateStatement.executeBatch();

            resultSet.close();
            setupStatement.close();
            idInsertStatement.close();
            secretNumberUpdateStatement.close();
            readStatement.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // Handle any errors
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Closing the connection.");
            if (conn != null) try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
        }
```

The error I am getting for that update query is

```
SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

As mentioned, the same error was showing for the previous queries before I added a semicolon at the end of them, and now it only shows for the final one.

Comment: As `secret_number` is a VARCHAR, its value should be enclosed in quotes.  However, far better would be to use PreparedStatement instead to handle that for you - that is more secure (preventing SQL injection attacks), and also handles eg if your value includes a quote character itself.

Comment: Your CREATE TABLE statement is missing a closing `)` character. The syntax error gives you a clue by saying `...near '' at line 1`, meaning it got confused at the end, expecting a closing parenthesis, but there was none. Normally the syntax error shows what follows the position it got confused, but in this case that's the end of your statement, so there is nothing following.

Comment: You are trying to insert `NULL` into both of your columns, but the first one, `id`, has a `NOT NULL` constraint.

Comment: @racraman and Bill Karwin Both of your solutions were the issue. I will look into using a prepared statement as well, Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JettoMartínez it does work with the Null values as that field is auto incremented, and it hasn't been an issue, but thank you for the insight as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have created the column `secretNumber` as a `VARCHAR(20)`, I would check to make sure `secretNumber` is at most 20 characters long before adding it.

On line 30 you have the following.

```java
secretNumber = "R" + env + id + randomDigit;
```

So, you can either use the debugger, or on line 31 you can put the following.

```java
if (secretNumber.length() > 20) throw new Exception();
```

If that doesn't work, you can try single quotes around the values, I guess.

```java
String updateSecretNumber =
   "UPDATE secret_number_generator " +
   "SET secret_number = '" + secretNumber + "' " +
   "WHERE id = '" + id + "'";
```

Additionally, a semicolon at the end of a single statement is not required.

Comment: The quotation marks around the secretNumber were the main issue, as well as I was missing a closing ")" in my create table statement. Thank you for the insight!

Comment: Try not to construct the SQL string like that. Instead, use PrepareStatement. It will remove syntax or escaping problems while at the same time protecting you from SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 2):

While the previous example gives you the desired result it can easily break on malicious variable values. This version is hardened against SQL injection:

Use a PreparedStatement like so:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
    "UPDATE secret_number_generator " +
    "SET secret_number = ? " +
    "WHERE id = ?";
ps.setString(1, secretNumber);
ps.setString(2, id);
int count = ps.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("updated %d rows", count);
```